# Compiling Beaglebone Black Linux image for QT and 4Dsystems LCD cape

Tags: linux, yocto, buildroot, touch-screen, beagleboneblack

I have researched a lot into buildroot and yocto compilation for BBB and understand qt configs / layers for both. However I can’t seem to get the 4.3” Touchscreen cape to work. I have tried comparing Angstrom and Debian images (where it does work) but have no idea why. I am close to the point of throwing the BBB and cape in the bin and going with a simpler option; but as one last attempt can anyone help?